# Facing Frequent Connection loss from DB2 (using ibm_db version- 2.4.1)

Tags: node.js, db2

I am using a NodeJS application to create a connection with DB2 server using ibm_db package from npm. When the application first starts the connection is made successfully and Querying the database provide appropriate results. However After some period of time somehow The application loose connectivity to database.

I am using connection pooling and after every query I do db.close().
The next time for the succeeding query I do pool.open() again, and I can see the pool still contains the connection strings and have the pool size 2,

However I suspect the connection get staled somehow, as after this point of time Querying the database does not give any error on the instant but also does not bring back any results, I constantly see empty array in response, and after a few minute it logs -

> SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.    Communication
> protocol    being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used:
> "SOCKETS".    Location    where the error was detected: "9.21.85.159".
> Communication    function detecting    the error: "send".  Protocol
> specific error code(s): "10032",    "*", "*".    SQLSTATE=08001

**DB2 instance is hosted on IBM Cloud - LINUX OS,
I am using NodeJS version - 8, specifically 8.11.5. I am making indirect TCP/IP Connection using ibm_db package from npm**

To fix this issue I have to manually restart my application again. But the issue appear again after some time.

This process keeps on repeating.
I am not sure what is causing this. Please help me. I am stuck with this issue

Here is the code I am using to connect to database. and handle queries.

I have tried Updating the ibm_db module version but this still won't work.

```
let Pool = ibmdb.Pool;
pool = new Pool({autoCleanIdle: true});
pool.setMaxPoolSize(2);
let cn = null;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {

    if(process.env.IBMDB2_CONN_STRING) cn = process.env.IBMDB2_CONN_STRING;
    else {
      console.error('##############################################################');
      console.error('##############################################################');
      console.error('##############################################################');
      console.error('Connection String for DB is Undefined.');
      console.error('##############################################################');
      console.error('##############################################################');
      console.error('##############################################################');
      process.exit(1);
    }
}

const runQuery= (query,paramsValueArray)=>{
  
    console.log('inside runQuery');
     return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
       console.log('inside promise')
       try {
         
        console.log(pool, '---POOL---');
        pool.open(cn, (err, db) => {
        console.log('inside pool.open')
        if(err) {
            console.log(err, '---error inside runQuery---');
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(query, '----runquery----');
        console.log(paramsValueArray, '---params  value array---');
        db.query(query,paramsValueArray,function(err,data){
 
           if(err)  {
             console.log('error in executing Query, ----in runQuery----')
             db.close(() => {
               console.log('connection Disconnected');
             });
             reject(err);
             return;
           }
           
           console.log('no error in query')
            resolve(data);
            db.close(() => {
              console.log('connection Disconnected');
             
              return;
            });
            
               
            });
        })
       }
       catch(err) {
         reject(err);
       }
     });
 };
```

No error shows at the moment. but results shows empty array.

and after some time of the query being processed an error shows saying -

> SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.    Communication
> protocol    being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used:
> "SOCKETS".    Location    where the error was detected: "9.21.85.159".
> Communication    function detecting    the error: "send".  Protocol
> specific error code(s): "10032",    "*", "*".    SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: EDIT your question to add new facts:  what is your Db2-server operating system (z/OS, i-series, linux/unix/windows) ?   what operating-system (give exact version) runs your node.js ?  Is the TCP/IP connection *direct* to the target Db2-database, or is it *indirect* (for example via a gateway like Db2-connect)?

Comment: @mao , I have edited the question and added DB2-server OS detail and Node.js Version. However I am using ibm_db package to connect to DB2 so I think that would be indirect, is that correct?

Comment: So your TCP/IP connection (from some unspecified Linux distro/version)  is to Db2-LUW hosted on IBM cloud.   It may be that the connection(s) to the Db2-database are timing out due to inactivity or other reason, and the pool software is not automatically reconnecting. You may need to configure db2dsdriver.cfg for automatic reconnects. Your version of node.js is quite old, have you tried 10.16 or higher in a test environment ?  This issue might be about configuration and you might get more specific advice from the node-ibm_db issues list on github.

Comment: @mao How do I configure db2sdriver.cfg? The Db2 instance service is taken from IBM Cloud. how do I access its config. files?

Comment: Refer to the suggestions relating to "pool" and "reconnect" on the github node-ibm_db. The IBM documentation is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.kc.doc/welcome.html  .

Comment: In particular, careful study of issue 497 (with fix in ibm_db 2.5.2 ) may be helpful https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/497

Comment: @mao Thank you for sharing this issue, that's exactly whats happening to me. I will try those changes and let you know if I that fixes the error in my case or not :) thank you very much. I hope this works.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  If not, edit your question to show the `db2dsdriver.cfg` contents (mask hostname/ip-address details) from the hostname running node.js, and also show in plain text the output of the `.../clidriver/bin/db2level`  command, on the hostname that runs node.js, assuming that you are using the `ODBC and CLI driver` supplied by IBM, and also show your HA configuration detail for your Db2-cloud environment .